# How to find out which function is cased hang on main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading

Is there any way to easy to debug out what cause my hang on main thread?
when I debug without enable the breakpoint, there's a moment that the tableView will hang for a while, but how to found what cause that?

**EDIT**
I have upload the thread status when the app is hang, and I click the Pause button. show bellow:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**  I have upload the Profile of Instruments, which selected duration is which the screen is hang.

[image]

**Edit**
I have create a root problem question about this.[Image download and save to file, Image read from file will cause lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202337/nsdata-writetofileatomically-and-uiimagecontentsoffile-will-cause-the-ui-c)

Comment: Use Profiling Instruments to detect where your app spends most of the time. It should be easy to debug.

Comment: thank, yes, I just found which code cause the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202337/image-download-and-save-to-file-image-read-from-file-will-cause-lock , but still can't found solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Instruments for that. Choose `Product / Profile`. Choose Time Profiler. Start profiling by pressing `Record` (the red circle). When the table view hangs, you'll most likely see a change in the graph. Select the region on the graph corresponding to the time when the table view hanged, and see what's being done on the main thread. You can find more info on Instruments on the web.

Another option is to start normal debugging, and then press "Pause" right when the tableView hangs. And then look at the stack trace for the main thread.

Comment: for the second one, after I click the Pause, there's almost only show nothing in main thread.

Comment: @JerryZhou, maybe the main thread is stuck waiting for some other thread (i.e. `dispatch_sync`)? If so, have a look at other threads, and you might find the one that is causing the freezing. What about instruments?

Comment: I have upload the screenShot for this.

Comment: I have checked again, there's several org.reactivecocoa.ReactiveCocoa.QueueScheduler(serial) in other thread, But I don't think that will block the MainThread.

Comment: @JerryZhou, hm... I hoped it would work. Well, try Instruments (Time Profiler) then.

Comment: I was doubt that if the org.reactivecocoa.ReactiveCocoa.QueueScheduler(serial) will stop main-thread, I have upload the latest screenshot for thread after pause.

Comment: Ok then, I found the problem who caused it. but can't found a better solution for it.

Comment: I have ask the problem in anther question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202337/image-download-and-save-to-file-image-read-from-file-will-cause-lock